# JSON - how to convert plain format into json format?

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I got the response after invoke from worklight adapter.

> {"text": "{\n  \"responseCode\" : \"00\",\n  \"responseMsg\" : null,\n 
>   \"buildFromAccountsMap\" : {\n    \"1000071000005844 D\" :
>   \"1000071000005844\",\n    \"1000791000030636 D\" :
>   \"1000791000030636\",\n    \"1001911000036935 D\" :
>   \"1001911000036935\",\n    \"1002021000029411 D\" :
>   \"1002021000029411\",\n    \"1005071000029666 D\" :
>   \"1005071000029666\",\n    \"1005071000033139 D\" :
>   \"1005071000033139\",\n    \"1005071000037533 D\" :
>   \"1005071000037533\",\n    \"1005071000038605 D\" :
>   \"1005071000038605\",\n    \"1005071000045298 D\" :
>   \"1005071000045298\",\n    \"1005071000045517 D\" :
>   \"1005071000045517\",\n    \"1005071000046989 D\" :
>   \"1005071000046989\",\n    \"1005071000056183 D\" :
>   \"1005071000056183\",\n    \"1005491000019560 D\" :
>   \"1005491000019560\",\n    \"2000071000163308 S\" :
>   \"2000071000163308\",\n    \"2000071000163361 S\" :
>   \"2000071000163361\"\n  }}

My worklight adapter

```
function buildFromAccounts(userId) {
    path = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'plain',
        path : path,
        body:{
            contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            content:
                JSON.stringify({
                    "userId": userId.toString()

                })
            }
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

The problem is, how I can convert this plain format into json format in worklight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you set for `returnedContentType`? JSON or plain?

Edit: since you are returning plain...
Try something akin to the following: `var obj = JSON.parse(response.text)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your backend returns json. no reason to treat it like a plaintext. change

```
returnedContentType : 'plain'
```

to

```
returnedContentType : 'json'
```

(optionally - omit this property at all, WL server will try to detect response type automatically)

Option #2 - you can always use

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```